# 'strictSsl' does not exist in type 'Options' in jwks-rsa 2+ version but its existing in jwks-rsa 1+ version

Tags: npm, jwt

TS2345: Argument of type '{ strictSsl: boolean; jwksUri: any; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Options'.
Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'strictSsl' does not exist in type 'Options'.